# Does xampp have a protection installed against mysql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

İt's been a while now that i've been trying to hack my own login form through various tutorials. None of which has been working for me. Which got me thinking if by downloading Xampp i've also downloaded a protection of some sort. İs it true? Here is the single line of code:

```
$cdquery = "SELECT name, surname, password, active FROM searcheng.try WHERE name='".$_POST['namen']."' AND password ='".$_POST['passworden']."' AND active = 1";
```

Some of the injections i tried were:

```
' OR '1'='1
' OR 1=1 --
'"; #
```

However nothing seems to work because it either returns blank, an error 
(check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a' AND active = 1' at line 1)
or "Account hasn't been activated" a safety check i put on this other bit of code:

```
if ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($cdresult)) {


 while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($cdresult)) {

   echo $rows['name'];
   echo $rows['surname'];
   echo $rows['password'];  
 }

 } else {
 echo "Account hasn't been activated";
}
```

Also, how can i store these functions in the database?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Store what functions in the database? Btw, you should stick to one topic per question.

Answer (score 1):

> if by downloading Xampp i've also downloaded a protection of some sort. İs it true?

No.

> returns an error (check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax )

It means you've got an injection.

You have to understand that injection is one thing and a *successful exploit* is another. Injection simply means that there is a possibility to inject some code. So you';ve got itm this code injection produced the syntax error. If you want to exploit it, you have to learn SQL.

Comment: Thanks, however, what would a successful exploit be in my specific case?

Comment: it depends on what query you want to have

Comment: +Your Common Sense please respond

Comment: Well you have to write a query that returns information about all users. You see, if your question is not about SQL injection but how to write a query that return all users, then it's different question